# Best way to authenticate with GitHub.js?

Tags: authentication, github, github-api, github.js

I have a JavaScript file that needs to use the GitHub API to get the contents of a file stored in a repository.

I am using [GitHub.js](http://github-tools.github.io/github/docs/3.1.0/index.html) to access the API, and it shows the following method for authentication:

```
// basic auth
var gh = new GitHub({
   username: 'FOO',
   password: 'NotFoo'
   /* also acceptable:
      token: 'MY_OAUTH_TOKEN'
    */
});
```

This code will be viewable inside the repository, as well as in the developer settings in the browser. GitHub does not allow you to commit a file that contains an OAuth token, and publicly displaying the username and password for my account is obviously a non-option as well.

Is there any other way to do authentication? I tried using the client-id and client-secret but it doesn't seem to take those as valid credentials.

Answer (score 0):

Try an [Installation Access Token](https://developer.github.com/apps/building-github-apps/authenticating-with-github-apps/). I can't remember the specifics but I used that link to set myself up.